# Why is Mitch McConnell blocking nominees to the Federal Election Commission?

Tags: united-states, nomination, fec

As at Sep 2019 - [we can see](https://www.salon.com/2019/08/27/fec-cant-enforce-election-laws-right-now-because-of-mitch-mcconnells-obstruction/) that the Federal Election Commission is down to three members, one short of its required quorum, making it toothless.

Mitch McConnell could allow hearings for the current nominee  but chooses not to.

My question is: **Why is Mitch McConnell blocking nominees to the Federal Election Commission?**

Answer (score 11):

The FEC is meant to be a bipartisan body, meaning there should be an equal number of Democrats as Republicans.  It is therefore customary for the President to work with the opposite party to ensure that this bipartisanship is maintained.

The last few appointments to the FEC have been in pairs, with one Democrat and one Republican being confirmed at roughly the same time.  While President Trump has nominated a Republican to replace Ann Ravel in 2017, he has yet to nominate a Democrat to the commission.  [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/fec-left-toothless-empty-seats-heading-2020/story?id=65215840) says it is possible that this is the reason that the Senate has been unable to move forward with confirmation.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the Trump administration is unusually slow at nominating people for almost any position no matter what it is.

Comment: With the panel currently having 3 members surely a singleton appointment is necessary eventually?

Comment: @Jonita If a singleton appointment does take place, it will likely be an independent.

Comment: Why do FEC members need to declare an affiliation with a party?  Given that the membership comprises representatives of both parties, why not let the parties put forward their chosen representatives?  It seems as if with the current situation the door is open to stack the commission in favor one way or the other by whoever has the senate majority.

Comment: @Joe Why? The overview of the commission says it's usually balanced between Republicans and Democrats (lets ignore the idea that this could cause suppression of 3rd parties) at the moment the panel has 3 members because a Republican resigned. The other two have been missing for longer and should be replaced as a pair, but presumably in the normal course a resignation means a single individual from the same party would be appointed. Or would an opposite party member have to resign so a new pair could be announced together?

Comment: So why won't Congress (Senate?) compel the president to nominate a Democrat? Or alternatively, legislate around the president? ... which brings us back to the original question.

Comment: @einpoklum: That would be an egregious violation of separation of powers. The president makes the appointments, per Article II of the Constitution, "by and with the advice and consent of the Senate." It is not for Congress to legislate how the President exercises his Constitutional powers.

Comment: @Kevin: Can't you just define the FEC members not to be "Officers of the United States"?

Comment: @einpoklum: No, you can't. The Constitution means what it means. Congress does not have the power to change its meaning in the fashion you suggest. There are more than two centuries' worth of jurisprudence on the meaning of "Officer of the United States." This sort of dodge has been litigated to death and can't be used now.